# logits and labels must have the same first dimension

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, kaggle

I am trying to create a recipe generator at kaggle using tensorflow and lstm. But I am totally stuck in something related to dimesions. Can someone point me out in the right direction?

https://www.kaggle.com/pablocastilla/d/kaggle/recipe-ingredients-dataset/ingredients-recomender-using-lstm-with-tensorflow/run/1066831

Thanks so much!

Comment: Could you please consider posting the relevant parts of your code directly in the post (links get broken/updated over time which is not useful for future readers) and add what you tried to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that

```
training_batches[0][1]
```

is a list and not a numpy.array, you should modify create_datasets accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an excerpt from the implementation of `seq2seq.sequence_loss(logits, targets, weights)`, which you use in your code:

```
with ops.name_scope(name, "sequence_loss", [logits, targets, weights]):
    num_classes = array_ops.shape(logits)[2]
    logits_flat = array_ops.reshape(logits, [-1, num_classes])
    targets = array_ops.reshape(targets, [-1])
    if softmax_loss_function is None:
      crossent = nn_ops.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
labels=targets, logits=logits_flat)
```

I believe the error you see is stemming from the last line in that code. The error message is self-explanatory:

> InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must have the same first
>   dimension, got logits shape [8,6714] and labels shape [2]

I.e. the size of the first dimension of `logits_flat` and `targets` must be the same. This translates directly to your input to `seq2seq.sequence_loss`: The first two dimensions of your `targets` and `logits` variable must be equal. So, either you are not using the same number of batches for the two variables or somehow your sequence length changed (which would be weird though).